# Can't restore packages on macOS Sierra

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-code, .net-core, macos-sierra

I'm trying to create a Web Application Basic [without Membership and Authorization] on Mac using .NET CORE and VSCode.

After creating a new project using

```
yo aspnet
```

command I'm trying to restore packages in my app folder but I get this error:

```
log  : Restoring packages for /Users/<user_name>/<app_name>/project.json...
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'Http' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception.
error:   Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module could not be found.
error:    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Done: 1.
```

(I've already installed all dependencies and tools to execute ASP.NET on mac)

Comment: Drop that project and use `dotnet new` first to create a project for testing. An out-of-date template usually leads to errors. You should also include the output of `dotnet --version` in such questions so people know which version of SDK you are using.

Comment: You said you installed the tools, but did you also install the runtime just to be sure? `Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module could not be found` sounds more like that the .NET Core runtime isn't installed correctly

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the [.NET Core download page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) about installing OpenSSL and creating the symlinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not install the OpenSSL as described in the tutorial at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos, running the command below should resolve the issue.

```
brew update; brew install openssl; mkdir -p /usr/local/lib; ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/; ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/;
```

In my computer, if I uninstall the OpenSSL, the same error happens.