# AWSSDK Got error `Unable to load DLL 'Crypt32.dll'` in macos

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, dllnotfoundexception

I don't know the reason but it might be because macOS was recently updated to `10.13.1 (17B48)`. The code that used to worked some weeks ago just crash with this error

> "Unable to load DLL 'Crypt32.dll': The specified module could not be found.\n (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

It only happen in macos and not the production platform (docker linux). And it got thrown from the `lambda.GetFunctionConfigurationAsync`

The import config is `<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Lambda" Version="3.3.*" />` and restored as `AWSSDK.Core 3.3.19`

> dotnet --info
>   .NET Command Line Tools (2.1.0-preview1-006547)
>
> Product Information:
>    Version:            2.1.0-preview1-006547
>    Commit SHA-1 hash:  3471d43796
>
> Runtime Environment:
>    OS Name:     Mac OS X
>    OS Version:  10.13
>    OS Platform: Darwin
>    RID:         osx.10.12-x64
>    Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.0-preview1-006547/
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.3
>     Build    : a9190d4a75f4a982ae4b4fa8d1a24526566c69df

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819614/cant-restore-packages-on-macos-sierra ? And try uninstall and reinstall of .NET core 2 framework

Comment: @rupps dotnet framework was opensource and available on every platform for decades and awssdk for dotnet is also available on crappy OSX I was forced to use. I can write both my app and server in proper framework like dotnet and C#. But the problem is MacOS just doesn't make sense in anything. Now I switch back to Windows and problem solved

Comment: @rupps AWS Lambda can run dotnet on linux properly for years. AWSSDK on dotnet can run correctly on both linux and windows. Just only MacOS that try to be problem. I don't think dotnet is the crap here but MacOS is

Comment: @rupps If you said that Java is also ripoff C++. C# is better than Java in every aspect, because it came out later and learn from what java had done wrong but not fixing. And we all know OSX is Unix but Unix is not linux and problem here is somehow from what OSX was done on the top of Unix because it actually can run on the same OSX machine last month before upgrade to High Sierra. Not to mention the root account bug that leaked along with this upgrade, so , what the hell is this proper OS?